# Database access from outside using Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, postgresql, database, remote-access

I want to access a database which is in my Windows Server 2012 R2 from outside, means from an other PC. Not on the same network. What is the best configuration for it?
Should I use a VM for the DB? Should I use a VPN-connection for access? Do you recommend a HW-Firewall or is for example a Cisco-Device sufficient?
Can someone help please and maybe deliver an instruction?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! The important question is: is there a NAT (Network Address Translation) happening between the other PC and the database server? If both are in the same private network, or the database server has a static public IP address, it might be easy. If there is a NAT device anywhere between them, you may not be able to make it work without the cooperation of the administrator of the NAT device.

Comment: They are not in the same network. Could I reach this with a VPN connection, could I?

Comment: I think there is no NAT